# Get View that was clicked in recycler view

Tags: android, click, touch, listener, android-recyclerview

I have implemented the touch listener for the recycler view and it is working well for single tap events and double tap events and it returns the viewholder that i clicked on but i want to know the view that was clicked on within that view holder.How exactly can this be done?

[image: ViewHolder]

This is what each item looks like in the recycler view.What i need to do is when the user clicks on the share icon it just fires an intent to share data but when anything other than the share is clicked it should go to another screen where further details are provided,also i need to listen for long press so that i can delete the item that was long pressed.

Comment: What you mean by *but i want to know the view that was clicked*

Comment: @Blackbelt when you have ViewHolder with textview and imageView (for example) he wants to know that his imageview was tapped on, not just that the viewholder was tapped on. Anyways OP , I'd recommend using method where you implement OnClickListener in your viewholder and use interface. The touch listener was not flexible enough for me when i tried it (although it might be possible).

Comment: @Blackbelt exactly what poss said.If i have an image inside my view holder i want to know when the image was clicked specifically.poss i have tried the click listener which worked but the touch event also fires at the same time.How did you stop the touch event from firing when the click event responded.

Comment: remove the touch listener? you don't need both

Comment: updated question to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

one way to achieve it is to declare an interface, like

```
public interface OnRecyclerViewItemClick {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

and let your `Fragment`/`Activity` implements it. Keep a reference to the it in your `RecyclerView.Adapter`, and pass it to your `ViewHolder`. The latter implements `View.OnClickListener` too, and you set `this` as click listener for all the view you are interesting to retrieve the click event

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private OnRecyclerViewItemClick mItemClick;

    public MyViewHolder(View v, OnRecyclerViewItemClick listener) {
        super(v);
        mItemClick = listener;
        v.findViewById(R.id.image_view).setOnClickListener(this);
        v.findViewById(R.id.text_view).setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mItemClick != null) {
            mItemClick.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

you can add the parameters you need to the interface's method

Comment: Updated the question to provide a little insight at to what i am trying to do.I have implemented the click listener and it is working but the touch listener also fires at the same time and i need to perform separate tasks based on each.

Comment: when `onItemClick` is fired. Check view.getId() and act accordingly to its value

Comment: OnClick of anywhere other than the share button i need go to another activity which is being handled by the single tap of the touch listener but when i click on the share button the touch listener is fired first which cause it to go to another activity and then the click listener is fired for sharing,i need to separate these two events out.